# Achieving independent appbar snap

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-appbarlayout

The playstore (and whatsapp) have a very cool effect on their appbar.

This is a sample:

[image]

When I try to replicate it, in my layout there's:

```
CoordinatorLayout
 + AppBar
   - CollapsibleToolbar
 + FrameLayout (to load fragments inside it, with layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

In my implementation, the content inside the framelayout always snaps back when the appbar snaps back. What I'm trying to achieve is something similar to the screenshot above, where the content stays where it is while the appbar is snapping back up.

Any clue on how to achieve this?